# Stack Exchange site title is not readable

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com

I was checking the Stack Exchange [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) community with Windows, using Google Chrome, and I found this:

[image]

I experimented with a lot of monitor sizes and found out with a larger title it gets worst. I also tried Firefox. If you click on it you can see the full title:

[image]

Is this a common error or is it a bug that should fixed?

Comment: Looks like a valid bug report. Unfortunately, I don't immediately see a simple solution. The design of the page doesn't lend itself to making the container "bubble" bigger, and ExpressionEngine is a product name so we can't correctly separate it onto two lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 3 options:

1. Put 3 dots where there is not enough space for the text.

[image]

2. Show the full text on mouse hover with an animated scroll.
3. Show the full text on mouse hover with a dialog box like below:

[image]

I saw another problem there, every dialog on the end of the screen should open to the left side the element to avoid a horizontal scroll.